# Can't get Arduino output to work using IRremote Arduino library

Tags: arduino, infrared, arduino-uno, code

I'm trying to send an infrared signal to my LED-strip-receiver, but no code makes the LED work (light.)

I have the IRremote.h Arduino library installed on version 1.18.15 and I found this example/test code on the internet, that somebody else got to work:
`
[code](https://justpaste.it/8b7qv)

It doesn't matter what code I use the IR LED still doesn't work. I've tried multiple codes.

I tried with a normal LED instead, which didn't work either. (Both LEDs are intact.)

My LED is set to pin 3 PWM and ground on my Arduino Uno.

I tried to put `Serial.println(" works") ; break;` at the end of my IRsend code string, but I never saw the printed message in the console. So for some reason the code snippet didn't get run, but why?

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

````
include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10000);
  //Power//
  irsend.sendNEC(0xF720DF, 32); //Power Code
  Serial.println("Power");
  delay(10000);
  //Volume Up//
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0xF7807F, 32); //Volume Up Code
    Serial.println("Volume Up");
    delay(250);
  }
  delay(5000);
  //Volume Down//
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0xF700FF, 32); //Volume Down Code
    Serial.println("Volume Down");
    delay(250);
  }
  delay(5000);
  //Netflix//
  irsend.sendNEC(0xF750AF, 32); //Netflix Code
  Serial.println("Netflix");
  delay(10000);
}
```
````

Comment: We can't see your circuit, code, wiring or anything, so unless you provide more information, it is impossible to answer questions like why the code does not run or what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Click on the link. The code should be there. The curcuit is just a LED connected to the Arduino using pin 3 and ground. There isn't really much to it.

Comment: How do we know you don't have a loose wire or something? Or the LED anode and cathode swapped?

Comment: Because I have tried it 10 times with different wires, and checking if the LED does work (which it does) and is placed properly. How would a schematic or a picture help you know if there's a loose wire anyway?

Comment: A loose wire can be see from photo? What if the LED is OK, have you checked if a IR receiver can react to it? How do you know the timing, protocol, device code etc you send over infrared are compatible with the LED controller you are using? Have you tried to analyze what the original remote sends out? It's the same with TVs, a Brand X remote will not work with Brand Y TV.

Comment: Use inbuilt code editor to attach code, instead of a fishy looking link.

Comment: I have used my phone to check if the infrared light blinks when the code is runned. It doesn't. I used a normal blue LED instead of the infrared one, and it doesn't light either. I also tried to print something in the console right after the irsend code, but I never saw anything in the console. So I'm thinking the Arduino is jumping over that sending code snippet, and it never gets sent.

Comment: I wrote "irsend.sendNEC(0xF720DF, 32); Serial.println(" works") ; break;" in the same line. So it should print out "works" in the console if the line is runned, right?

Comment: @MituRaj, sorry I tried but couldn't get it to work. But I can post it somewhere else if you'd like?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to initialize the IR sender module first before using it? To tell it which pin to use etc?

Comment: I don't mean the physical IR LED, I mean the Arduino library code module called IRsend that you are using.

Comment: I thought I needed it too. But it looks like there is a standard pin at pin 3 PWM.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the call to initialize the IRsender.h library is omitted.

Initialize it with the begin method like shown the documentation and examples.

Comment: Link to documentation and examples?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/irremote/ Should get you started.

Comment: Could you write the code snippet i need? Because I'm not quite sure what you mean by it. And I don't know where to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Also, Thanks for your help

Comment: Most likely you just need to call irsend.setSendPin(xxx); in the setup, and replace the xxx with the IR LED pin number. The library has been changed so much it is not easy to keep track of how it works, so old versions might have worked without any initializing if they expect the LED is on hardware PWM pin, but it seems new versions don't use hardware PWM.

Comment: Good you were around. Thanks, man! How did you even find out?

Comment: I read the documentation, manual, and because of their poor quality, I read the IR library ource code. I have never used an Arduino BTW, so good thing if it it worked. You might find more Arduino aware folks at arduino stackexchange.